# Scroll To Top Button and open new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want, When I click on a button to go to the top and change the page.

I have this

code js>

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```

code html>

```
<a href="<?php $url->_getURL('openpage'); ?>" class="scrollToTop">Domestic Electrical installation</a>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the `scrollTo()` method and `navigator.href` property.

Try this:

```
//with JQuery:
$(".scrollToTop").click(function(){
window.scrollTo(0,0); //Scrolls to a x,y pair(x = vertical y = horizontal
navigator.href = newURL; //Sets the page of the current tab to a url value
}
```

---

## Good luck!

Comment: you can writte for me complete code.. iam not very good.. for make myself.. tnx

Comment: There. I edited the code, and you can now use that instead of your click handling event. Glad I could help.